# Pinterest button shows image options from different posts

Tags: posts, images

I used the SassySocialShare wordpress plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/sassy-social-share/) to add a Pinterest sharing button to my blog. The blog's not live yet so I can't share a link.

But this is what's happening. When you click on the Pinterest button, it shows all the image pin options from that post as well as some images from other posts. The images from other posts shouldn't be there at all.

For example, when I click on the Pinterest button for my mango drink post, it shows 4 mango images (correct) and 1 salmon burger image (incorrect). I pinned the salmon burger image just to see what info it was carrying and in Pinterest, it's description shows the SEO title for the original mango drink post and the url for the original mango drink post. So strange.

I tried installing the official Pinterest button chrome extension and it's the same problem there, when you click on that button. So, I don't think the problem lies with the Sassy social share plugin.

Please help me fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by just deleting the previously uploaded images from the media library, and re-adding them. So simple. Can't believe I didn't think of it earlier.